# Unlock a html button with JS

Tags: javascript, html, button

A very simple problem potentially. An inverse of the function that locks a button is not working to unlock the button. What is the workaround? Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/tearex/pgju1mw9/10/

```js
function lock() {
    document.getElementsByName("BUTTONBLOCK")[0].disabled = true;
}

function unlock() {
    document.getelementsbyname("BUTTONBLOCK")[0].disabled = false
}
```

```html
<td>
    <input name="BUTTONBLOCK" ID="I" type="button" value="lock itself" data-mini="true" title="test" onclick="lock()">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="PERSONA" ID="yousingular" type="button" value="unlock the other button" data-mini="true" onclick="unlock())">
</td>
```

Comment: `onclick="unlock())"`

Comment: I think you missed a ";"

Comment: you missspelled `getElementsByName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a couple of issues but mostly just attention to details:

In your HTML code there is a spare closing parenthesis `)` when calling the unlock function:

```html
<td>
    <input name="BUTTONBLOCK" ID="I" type="button" value="lock itself" data-mini="true" title="test" onclick="lock()">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="PERSONA" ID="yousingular" type="button" value="unlock the other button" data-mini="true" onclick="unlock()">
</td>
```

In your JS code on the unlock function the `getelementsbyname` is all lowercase while it should be titleCase:

```
function lock() {
    document.getElementsByName("BUTTONBLOCK")[0].disabled = true;
}
function unlock() {
    document.getElementsByName("BUTTONBLOCK")[0].disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the html onclick command, thank you. Still, using null is not working... https://jsfiddle.net/tearex/pgju1mw9/13/

Comment: @secr had you read and applied both fixes? Your fiddle still does not show the correct `getElementsByName`

Comment: ah, sorry, I was not aware capitalisation was crucial. Here it is, working. Thank you, Felipe
https://jsfiddle.net/tearex/pgju1mw9/15/

Answer (score 0):

Your function call to getelementsbyname is invalid, please use

```
document.getElementsByName("BUTTONBLOCK")[0].disabled = false;
```

Comment: Thank you, Giliam. https://jsfiddle.net/tearex/pgju1mw9/15/ It works now, but it was spelling that mattered. null vs false - no difference. Your code does work once copied verbatim.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that Javascript is a case-sensitive language, which is very useful, but can be anoying when encountering bugs like these.